# Какой из двух архитектурных подходов быстрее и почему?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Итак, имеется бэкенд на Laravel + MySQL. Задача следующая — в системе есть сущности (Eloquent Models) «статьи», каждая из которых является записью в таблице БД (собсна, это следует из того, что это модель).

Мне нужно добавить "теги" к статьям, по которым я смогу находить связанные статьи в других частях системы. При этом "теги" могут быть не только у статей, но у и других сущностей.

На данный момент работает так: в модели "статьи" добавлен $cast атрибут tags, который представляет собой массив с простым текстом. Соответственно, для поиска статей по тегам приходится использовать полнотекстовый поиск типа were('tags', 'like', '%'.$Tag_to_find.'%').

Есть опасения, что при росте числа тегов и базы в целом, такой полнотекстовый поиск будет работать медленно.

Существует другой подход - использовать для тегов отдельную модель и использовать стандартные отношения, предоставляемые Laravel. Однако тут много сложностей, т.к. в моем проекте есть несколько баз данных, но не все типы отношений позволяют указывать Connection, поэтому в этом случае мне придется строить достаточно костыльные конструкции.

Собственно вопрос в следующем - какой из подходов быстрее и почему?

Если я использую модель, я добавлю дополнительную промежуточную таблицу и, поскольку у меня несколько разных баз данных, количество запросов увеличится. Полнотекстовый поиск действительно так медленно работает как везде пишут или можно не париться?

Comment: Почему запись в поле массива с простым текстом не оказывает никакой сложности на наличие нескольких БД, а создание дополнительной таблицы оказывает?!

Comment: @ArchDemon Потому что в данный момент я использую не модели, а фасад DB и могу указывать нужный connection.

Как я написал в запросе - не все отношения позволяют указать connection

Comment: В Laravel соединение можно указывать непосредственно у модели. Думаю правильно было бы создать отдельную модель которая бы имела полиморфную связь с другими моделями. По факту добавится две таблицы: tags и таблица связи tag_,model

Comment: @YauhenKib  Да, для самой модели я, разумеется, могу указать connection, но статьи-то находятся в отдельной базе, т.е. connection мне надо указывать именно для отношения, а это, как я уже писал, возможно не для каждого типа отношений.

То, что использовать для этого модели "правильнее" с точки зрения архитектуры Laravel мне понятно, но вопрос всё же про то, какой вариант будет работать быстрее.

Есть определённые сомнения что две таблицы и возросшее число запросов будут быстрее поиска по одному столбцу.

Comment: В таком случае делайте как считаете проще. Для любого выбранного вами решения в будущем можно будет применить оптимизацию.